# passing props as classNames in next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

I am trying to have the header of each of my app's pages change color based on the current page. How I am trying to achieve this:

```
<Header className="headerBitcoin"></Header>
```

What I want is the be able to have the header component present on all 4 pages, and then just change the className to another prop to change the background but not anything else.

And the header component itself

```
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";
export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <div >
      <div className={props.className}>aaaaa</div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <div className={styles.tab}>a</div>
        <div className={styles.tab}>a</div>
        <div className={styles.tab}>a</div>
        <div className={styles.tab}>a</div>
      </div>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

At the moment the styles for the tabs and row are working but the header is not getting its style applied.

I checked the console and found the header is getting the className `headerBitcoin` passed to it, however the row beneath it has the className of `"Home_row__88lPM"`

 This is my first time working with next.js, and I know I am doing something wrong because this works in React. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you have your `headerBitcoin` stylings defined?

Comment: I had them in my modules.css, I realized my error and put the css in my global css, now it is working. 
If you would please turn your comment in to an answer I will give you the reputation you deserve for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it's not being applied because you have the `headerBitcoin` styles defined in your CSS module.

If you want to apply a class that way (`className="headerBitcoin"`), you need to define the class in your global CSS instead.

If you meant to use the `headerBitcoin` defined in `Home.module.css`, then you'll want to change the `className` to use the scoped `styles`.

```js
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <div >
      <div className={styles[props.className]}>aaaaa</div>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

don't do this:

```
<div className={props.className}>aaaaa</div>
```

try this instead:

```
<div className={styles[props.className]}>aaaaa</div>
```

I think this should works